# i3wm fonts too tiny

Tags: fonts, screen, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo T470s. I want to use i3 as wm as I did on my previous laptop. First the gtk-fonts were way too large. I installed gnome and changed to gdm which made the issue go away.

Now the fonts are generally too small on my Laptop screen (2560x1440) but fine for my second screen (1680x1050). The resolution is prefectly sharp but everything (windows and programs) is almost unreadable. I have tried to scale the screen with xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.6x0.6 --mode 2560x1440 but then everything gets blurry. How can I adjust the font size correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that Desktop Manager you are using .. but for me I can go to Start>Settings>Appearance then click on the fonts tab and change the Default Font settings. .. this will do it over both monitors though so the fonts on the 1050 screen will seem big due to the resolution difference between monitors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i3 is a tiled window manager without a start menu etc. It only organizes the windows and pulls the other information from elsewhere. Hence I tried xrandr but so far it didn't do the trick.

In Unity the fonts a re just fine, I want to set them for i3.